# Is Infinite Product of Hausdorff spaces Hausdorff with product topology?

Tags: general-topology

There's a theorem in Munkers that says if Xa is a Hausdorff space then infinite or finite(the book didn't mention if "a" comes from a finite or infinite set) product of them is Hausdorff with box or product topology
I could prove it for box topology but it seems that this theorem works for product topology if "a" comes from a finite set because open set in product topology is product of finitely many open sets.
if "a" is infinite that causes problem

Comment: The goal is to separate a pair of distinct functions in the product. That means there's at least one coordinate where they differ. Try using the Hausdorff property of the corresponding coordinate to get a basic open set separating them.